# What `**config` does with dot_env values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dotenv

i have `.env` file and I am importing it with:

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values

config = dotenv_values('{}/.env")
```

and using this config as `**config`

But i need to add my key, values in my `.env` but when I do this the code failt to run. I think this is happening because of the `**config`

Can someone telling me how can I add my `key:value` in my `.env` withou break the code?

Comment: Are you wondering what ``**config`` does *or* how to fix your problem of having additional keys?

Comment: hey man, both things actually.

Comment: So, are you adding values in the `.env` file itself, or trying to add values in python?

Comment: I am adding values to .env file

Comment: `**config` expands that dictionary as if you had specified all those values as parameters. Presumably it's used in a function call like `my_func(**config)`, which will have the effect of passing each key:value pair in `.env` to `my_func()`.

Comment: Let's backtrack a bit: for a good question, you should show the actual error message, with the full stack trace.

Comment: And here I'm going to bet that the value you're trying to add is not accepted by the function you're calling.

Comment: `**config` by itself is a syntax error, because it's not an expression. It's *only* valid as *part* of the function-call syntax.